# What (if any) is the difference between codec and protocol?

Tags: protocols, theory, codec

This is a somewhat theoretical question that risk being downvoted.

It would, however, be of great help, if answered, e.g. in cases of UI translation/localization.

What (if any) is the substantial difference in meaning between *codec* and *protocol*?

Answer (score 0):

### (Communications) Protocol

A [Communications protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_protocol) defines in what manner two systems can communicate. It is not an actual program.

One could loosely compare a protocol to an interface as used in e.g. Java and C#. It defines how you are able to "speak" with an object that is an instance of a class that implements said interface. An example of a protocol is the Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) which, among other things, defines the format of each message sent over a network link.

### Codec (encoder/decoder)

A [codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codec), in the most general sense, is a program that is able to convert data to and from a set of specific formats, e.g. from the format that a video file is encoded on disk to a format that is understood by the graphics stack provided by the OS/kernel. [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/about.html), for example, contains a number of codecs to be able to play a wide variety of audio and video files.